# C# Sql connection string, trying to connect to local db from another computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have a local SQL Server database that I'm trying to connect to via the connection string in my application in C#.

I have tried with this connection string, I have left Password blank because I have no password given in SQL login credentials:

```
Data Source=myComputerIP,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial 
Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=;
```

I have enabled TCP/IP and started SQL Web Browser in SQL Server configuration manager, opened port 1433, SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
I'm getting an error in C#

> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing the connection to the server.

Am I using wrong connection string?

My login to SQL Server DB:
[image: LOGIN CREDENTIALS]

Comment: can you check if your sql service is running or not ? you can check this by go to services and check if sql agent or sql server agent is running or not.....

Comment: @piyushsanadhya Everything is running but the SQL Server Agent. I have set the start mode on Automatic and tryed to start the service in SQL Configuration Manager but got this error: "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult event log or other applicable error logs for details"

Comment: can you force start the service , try restarting the system also sometimes that works too :)

Comment: @piyushsanadhya Restarted system, still getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your attached PNG, it appears you're using SQLExpress.  By Default this doesn't start on TCP port 1433.  Check the ports in the Configuration Manager->Network Config->ProtocolsFor...-> right-click TCP/IP, choose **properties** and click **IP Addresses** tab

Scroll to the bottom to set TCP Port under **IpAll** section to 1433, restart SQL Server, then try again (or use whatever ports appear to be defined here in your connection string)

I'd also recommend using SQL Server users for remote clients rather than windows - this way it's nicely separated from windows and domains etc.

Make sure your SQL Server is configured for mixed mode:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017

you can then create a LOGIN (for the database server) and a USER (for the specific database you want them to access) via SSMS, or you could use this script:

```
-- Creates the login remoteuser with password 'Pa$$word11'.  
CREATE LOGIN remoteuser
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Pa$$word11';  
GO  

-- Creates a database user for the login created above.  
CREATE USER remoteuser FOR LOGIN remoteuser;  
GO 

--grant remoteuser 'datareader' rights
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'remoteuser';

--grant remoteuser 'datawriter' rights
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'remoteuser';
```

You can do all the above through SSMS - add a login under the **Security** node, then in properties for the login set up database-level permissions too. The script is a bit more managable if you ever want to repeat the process though.

Connection string is then something like :

```
Data Source=192.168.0.55\SQLExpress;Database=MyDatabase;user=remoteuser;password=Pa$$word11
```

Comment: Set the port for TCP on 1433 (TCP Dynamic Ports is set on 49696), and restarted system. Now when I'm trying to connect with my C# program im getting a different error: Login failed for user: "". My connection string now is: 
Data Source=MyIpAddress,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog =MyDb, Integrated Security=True;

Comment: This will be trying to log in using the WINDOWS user of the remote client PC.  you'll have to allow this user access via security in SSMS.  Alternatively, just set your server for mixed mode (windows + SQL Server authentication), and add a SQL server user with a password and use that for remote connections.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some more details about using SQL Server auth rather than windows, as I really think that's the best approach for remote access generally and makes it possible to use this outside of your local domain...

Comment: I have created a new SQL admin user using this tutorial: [link] (http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.install.doc%2FSILKTEST-7FFBB86A-CREATINGNEWSQLSERVERADMINUSER-TSK.html) And used a new admin credentials in connection string.

And set SQL Server on mixed mode. But i'm still getting "Login failed for user"" " error. This is getting very frustrating :D

The IP addres that I am using in connection string is the IP address of a computer where the SQL server is. Is this correct IP?

Comment: Yes, it should be the PC with SQL Server on.  Do you still have 'integrated Security=true' in the connection string?  if so. it'll still be trying to use windows authentication.  Remove that bit if there (See example connection string in my answer)

Comment: My connection string looks like this : 
`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyIP\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog =MyDb,User ID=user;Password=user;");`

Comment: `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyIP\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog =MyDb;User ID=user;Password=user;");`  - you have a comma between the 'initial catalog' and 'User Id' parts, but should be a semicolon... maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Aaah yes, that comma was the problem, found it myself too after posting my connection here :) Anyway it works now(for now ;) ). Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Windows Authentication so you must set also Integrated Security = true. Remove the User ID and Password.

With Integrated Security = true, the connection string will get the credentials of the user who runs the application

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a microsoft sql server in a docker container on my macbook pro from 2015, was getting this error when running my C# VS2022 API and trying to connect to the db, had to put `Encrypt=True` in my connection string like so: `"DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;database=newcomparer;trusted_connection=false;User Id=sa;Password=reallyStrongPwd123;Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=True"`